# PHP assosiative array not working with foreach

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having problems with a form that posts information to create an order and an invoice. Among other variables, that has customer information and other stuff, I created one that is an associative array that looks like this.

Hello, thanks for the help, by suggestion of several users, if I `print_r($_POST)` this is the result:

```
Array ( 
[clientName] => Client inc
[clientTaxid] => 00000000000 
[clientAdress] => 1234 Main RD 
[clientAdress2] => City
[clientAdress3] => State 
[clientZipCode] => 53370 
[purchase] => Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        ['qty'] => 1 
        ['code'] => 1234 
        ['description'] => Product 1
        ['price'] => 1
        ['tax'] => .16
        ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        ['qty'] => 1 
        ['code'] => 3456 
        ['description'] => Product 2
        ['price'] => 3
        ['tax'] => .04
        ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        ['qty'] => 1 
        ['code'] => 6789 
        ['description'] => Product 3
        ['price'] => 5
        ['tax'] => 0.0
        ) 
     )
)
```

But when I try to use the foreach to loop through the array, I can't access the values stored.

```
foreach($_POST['purchase'] AS $pc){ 
  var_dump($pc);
  echo $pc['qty'];
  echo $pc['price'];
  echo $pc['code'];
}
var_dump($_POST['purchase'][0]['description']);
```

I just get blank without any errors. Am I creating my array wrong back from the form? Any suggestions? I might have being working too long and got stuck.
I tried var_dump as suggested and this is the result:

```
array(5) { 
    ["'qty'"]=> string(1) "1" 
    ["'code'"]=> string(4) "1234" 
    ["'description'"]=> string(3) "foo" 
    ["'price'"]=> string(1) "1" 
    ["'tax'"]=> string(3) ".16" 
}
array(5) { 
    ["'qty'"]=> string(1) "1" 
    ["'code'"]=> string(4) "3456" 
    ["'description'"]=> string(3) "foo" 
    ["'price'"]=> string(1) "3" 
    ["'tax'"]=> string(3) ".04" 
}
array(5) { 
    ["'qty'"]=> string(1) "1" 
    ["'code'"]=> string(4) "1234" 
    ["'description'"]=> string(3) "foo" 
    ["'price'"]=> string(2) "25" 
    ["'tax'"]=> string(3) ".16" 
}
NULL
```

---

Comment: That array is nested deeper than that

Comment: Do `print_r($_POST);` and post the contents in your question. Because if $_POST contains what you have posted, then your code would work.

Comment: Do you mind to share your the codes where you put your form for POST request?

Comment: turn on error reporting on your php...and post the error you're getting. To turn on include this line at the very beginning of you php script: `ini_set('display_errors', 1);error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: and from what I see is the `description` show with wrapped in quotes.Ie, `Product 1` should be `'Product 1'`

Comment: Hello, thanks for the help. If I print_r($_POST) this is the result:

Comment: What you show in your question should work. What does PHP Error logging tell you?

Comment: Try more complex structural  analysis: `var_dump($_POST['purchase'][0]['code']);` , and put `var_dump($pc)` within the foreach loop.

Comment: Martin, I get the following messages: "Notice: Undefined index: qty" and the same for the others

Comment: Ok so your POST data is not populated in the way you've laid it out on the question....

Comment: If you can edit and show us an example of your HTML form (for say, `qty` value) we can further confirm  my suspicions set out in my answer below. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## TL;DR

You should not use quotes in any part when defining array key names in an HTML form input/textarea `name` attribute.

---

> ```
> array(5) { 
>     ["'qty'"]=> string(1) "1" 
>     ["'code'"]=> string(4) "1234" 
>     ["'description'"]=> string(3) "foo" 
>     ["'price'"]=> string(1) "1" 
>     ["'tax'"]=> string(3) ".16" 
> }
> ```

This looks symptomatic of your issue, it seems to me that you're form data is including the quote marks in the form `name` definitions.

You need to clarify that your input name is:

```
<input name="purchase[0][qty]" value="5">
```

***NOT***:

```
<input name="purchase[0]['qty']" value="5"> <!-- should not be used this way -->
```

Or some similar mis-syntax. Your issue is ultimately caused by the PHP looking for the array value `qty` but you've set an array value of `'qty'`. Can you see the difference?

> Edit: *Which quote type you use doesn't matter, but just use ONE!*

Comment: Thank you very much, actually the inputs are created on the fly adding purchases to the order so they looked ike this: <input name="purchase[0]['qty']">. I eliminated the single quotes and problem solved. <input name=purchase[0][qty]>

Comment: you don't need to extra-quote your `name=` values in the HTML, Glad it works for you now! `:-)`

Comment: @EliasZarte please refresh and look at my final answer. Cheers